# UITableViewCell save button state

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, state

I try to create a simple player, that play audio from stream. And I have a table view with custom cells, that have play(pause) button and labels. And when I press on play button my current cell button title has been changed to pause title, but some others cells have been changed too, I can see that while scrolling up or down. As I have found out, I have to save the state of each cell in my tableview, but I don't clearly understand how I can do that. Could anyone please explain me, how I can do that.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.row == [self.audiosArray count]) {
    static NSString* identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell* firstCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!firstCell) {
        firstCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    firstCell.textLabel.text = @"LOAD MUSIC";
    firstCell.imageView.image = nil;
    return firstCell;

} else {
    AudioCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([AudioCustomCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];



    VYAudioFile *audioFile = [self.audiosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.artistLabel.text = audioFile.audioArtist;
    cell.titleLabel.text = audioFile.audioTitle;

    cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.cellsArray addObject:cell];
    return cell;

}
```

}

Play/Pause method:

```
 -(void) playAction:(UIButton *) sender
{
    if (![sender isEqual:nil]){
        self.audioIndex = sender.tag;
    }
    else {
        self.audioIndex = self.audioIndex + 1;
    }
    VYAudioFile *localAudio = [self.audiosArray objectAtIndex:self.audioIndex];

    self.previousCell = self.currentCell;
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    self.currentPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    self.currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.currentPath];

    NSLog(@"Sender tag : %d", sender.tag);


    if (!self.audioPlayer)
    {
        CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
        self.currentPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
        self.currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.currentPath];

        NSLog(@"!self.audioPlayer Cell button tag : %d", self.currentCell.playButton.tag);

        self.urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:localAudio.audioURL options:nil];
        self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.urlAsset];
        self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
        [self.audioPlayer play];
        [self.currentCell.playButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.previousCell = self.currentCell;
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.audioPlayer.rate == 1.0)
        {
            if ([self.currentCell isEqual:self.previousCell])
            {
                [self.audioPlayer pause];
                [self.currentCell.playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {

                [self.audioPlayer pause];
                [self resetPlayingAudio];

                CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
                self.currentPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
                self.currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.currentPath];

                 NSLog(@"self.audioPlayer && rate = 1 Cell button tag : %d", self.currentCell.playButton.tag);

                self.urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:localAudio.audioURL options:nil];
                self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.urlAsset];
                self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
                [self.audioPlayer play];
                [self.currentCell.playButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                self.previousCell = self.currentCell;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ([self.currentCell isEqual:self.previousCell] ) {
                [self.audioPlayer play];
                [self.currentCell.playButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else {
                [self resetPlayingAudio];

                CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
                self.currentPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
                self.currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.currentPath];

                NSLog(@"self.audioPlayer && rate = 0 Cell button tag : %d", self.currentCell.playButton.tag);

                self.urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:localAudio.audioURL options:nil];
                self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.urlAsset];
                self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
                [self.audioPlayer play];
                [self.currentCell.playButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                self.previousCell = self.currentCell;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Reset method:

```
    -(void) resetPlayingAudio
{
    if (self.audioPlayer.rate == 0.0)
    {
        [self.previousCell.playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.currentCell.playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.audioPlayer = nil;
        self.previousCell = nil;
        self.currentCell = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.audioPlayer pause];
        [self.previousCell.playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.currentCell.playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.audioPlayer = nil;
        self.previousCell = nil;
        self.currentCell = nil;
    }

}
```

AudioCustomCell class:

h-file:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AudioCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *artistLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *audioURL;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL buttonSelected;

@end
```

m-file:

```
    #import "AudioCustomCell.h"

@implementation AudioCustomCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.buttonSelected = NO;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: create a new  class or add   property to AudioCustomCell  bool type (playing or not)  to keep state of button  title  check condition on - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath .

Comment: @ SunilSingh, thank you for your answer. I have created a property in AudioCustomCell class and set it to NO in - (void)awakeFromNib method, and check it in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, but it didn't work. It has started to work more slowly only. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: provide latest code with AudioCustomCell class.